# How to plot arrival rate per hour of agents in enter block?

Tags: plot, anylogic

In my Anylogic model I let agents (trucks) enter the process blocks of a terminal. I want to plot this "arrival rate" per each hour of the day (e.g., 100 trucks between 12:00-13:00 arrived at this terminal), for all hours of the day (24). How can I do this the simplest way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a dataset `myDS` that does not update itself. Make sure to untick "use time as horizontal value" (we will use the time but in hour time units)
2. create an int variable `counter`
3. create an event that cyclically triggers every hour.

In the event code, write:

```
myDS.add(time(HOUR), counter); // stores number of arrivals in the past hour, stored at the current model time
counter = 0; // reset for next interval
```

In the `enter` block's "on enter" code, update the counter every time an agent arrives, using `counter++;`

Now you have a DS that stores how many agents arrived each hour. Plot that in a time plot and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Create a cyclic event that occurs every hour. Also add two datasets to your model: one named ***cumulativeArrivals***, the other ***arrivals*** (of course feel free to name the datasets whatever makes sense to you). Finally add a variable of type `int` called ***count*** with initival value 0.

[image]

Then, in the event action field, write the following code:

```
cumulativeArrivals.add(enter.out.count());

if( count == 0 )
   arrivals.add(cumulativeArrivals.getY(count));
else
   arrivals.add(cumulativeArrivals.getY(count) - cumulativeArrivals.getY(count-1));

count++;
```

[image]

Finally, add a plot with the following settings:
[image]